# Pandas DataFrame - grab value x rows below current row and compare

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a dataframe, Df of prices:

```html
Close_x
2121.25
2119.25
2119.5
2115.25
2120
2118
2115.25
2116.25
2116.25
```

If the first Close_x value (2121.25) is greater than the  Close_x value 9 rows down (2116.25) I want a new column, 'Profit' to add 100 like below:

```
Df['Profit'] = ''

for index, row in Df.iterrows():
    if Df['Close_x'].shift(9) > Df['Close_x']:
        Df['Profit'] == 100
    else:
        Df['Profit'] == -100
```

I've also tried this:

```
for index, row in Df.iterrows():
    if Df['Close_x'] + 9 > Df['Close_x']:
        Df['Profit'] == 100
    else:
        Df['Profit'] == -100
```

For both attempts, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Note that I have thousands of rows in Close_x so I would need this to iterate based on some rule like '9 rows down from the current value' rather than calling specific slices such as [:9].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
N = 3
Df['Profit'] = np.where(Df['Close_x'].shift(3) > Df['Close_x'], 100, -100)  
Df.loc[Df.index < N,'Profit'] = np.nan      
print (Df)
   Close_x  Profit
0  2121.25     NaN
1  2119.25     NaN
2  2119.50     NaN
3  2115.25   100.0
4  2120.00  -100.0
5  2118.00   100.0
6  2115.25  -100.0
7  2116.25   100.0
8  2116.25   100.0
```

Or maybe need:

```
N = 3
for index,row in Df.iterrows():
        if index < N:
            continue
        if(Df.loc[index-N, 'Close_x'] > Df.loc[index, 'Close_x']):
            Df.loc[index, 'Profit'] = 100
        else:
            Df.loc[index, 'Profit'] = -100            
print (Df)
   Close_x  Profit
0  2121.25     NaN
1  2119.25     NaN
2  2119.50     NaN
3  2115.25   100.0
4  2120.00  -100.0
5  2118.00   100.0
6  2115.25  -100.0
7  2116.25   100.0
8  2116.25   100.0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help here. I do want to keep the profit as either +100 or - 100, don't care about the actual profits as the price changes but rather just want the binary +100 or -100 if the price is higher or lower accordingly. I'm working on that loop right now. And yeah I def need to be using the loc function instead of what I was doing...

Comment: Unfortunately I never works with finance, so hard answer for me. But try edited answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Also first solution is faster, because no loops;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in Df.iterrows():
    if Df['Close_x'].shift(9) > Df['Close_x']:
        Df['Profit'] == 100
    else:
        Df['Profit'] == -100
```

You are iterating over your dataframe but not once using the variables index and row? That doesn't seem correct